# Is my approach to a threadsafe log class awful?

Tags: c++, logging, thread-safety, iostream, manipulators

I've been looking around at various approaches to the problem of threadsafe logging, but I haven't seen anything quite like this, so I dunno if it's somehow awful that I haven't noticed due to being a complete newbie to C++, threads and iostreams. It seems to work in the basic tests I've put it through.

Basically I have a Log class (creative, I know...) which has operator<< set up for the standard manipulators, so I can merrily pass in whatever I want.

However, I am aware that something like:

```
std::cout << "Threads" << " will" << " mess" << " with" << "this." << std::endl;
```

will potentially get interleaved when multiple threads are writing to cout (or wherever the Log ostream points). So, I have created some manipulators specific to the Log class that let me do this:

```
Log::log << lock << "Write" << " what" << " I" << " want" << std::endl << unlock;
```

I just want to know if this is an inherently awful idea, bearing in mind that I am willing to accept that users of the Log class will need to be disciplined with 'lock' and 'unlock'. I considered making 'std::endl' automatically unlock, but that just seems like it would create more headaches... I think undisciplined use should come out in testing anyway, but if anyone can see a way to make such uses cause compile-time errors, that would be nice.

I'd also appreciate any suggestions as to making my code any cleaner.

Here's a cut down version of the class for demonstration purposes; the whole thing has a few more constructors taking stuff like filenames, so not really relevant to the question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <fstream>

class Log{
public:
  //Constructors
  Log(std::ostream & os);
  // Destructor
  ~Log();
  // Input Functions
  Log & operator<<(const std::string & msg);
  Log & operator<<(const int & msg);
  Log & operator<<(std::ostream & (*man)(std::ostream &)); // Handles manipulators like endl.
  Log & operator<<(std::ios_base & (*man)(std::ios_base &)); // Handles manipulators like hex.
  Log & operator<<(Log & (*man)(Log &)); // Handles custom Log manipulators like lock and unlock.
  friend Log & lock(Log & log); // Locks the Log for threadsafe output.
  friend Log & unlock(Log & log); // Unlocks the Log once threadsafe output is complete.
private:
  std::fstream logFile;
  std::ostream & logStream;
  std::mutex guard;
};

// Log class manipulators.
Log & lock(Log & log); // Locks the Log for threadsafe output.
Log & unlock(Log & log); // Unlocks the Log once threadsafe output is complete.

void threadUnsafeTask(int * input, Log * log);
void threadSafeTask(int * input, Log * log);

int main(){
  int one(1), two(2);
  Log log(std::cout);
  std::thread first(threadUnsafeTask, &one, &log);
  std::thread second(threadUnsafeTask, &two, &log);
  first.join();
  second.join();
  std::thread third(threadSafeTask, &one, &log);
  std::thread fourth(threadSafeTask, &two, &log);
  third.join();
  fourth.join();
  return 0;
}

void threadUnsafeTask(int * input, Log * log){
  *log << "Executing" << " thread '" << *input << "', " << "expecting " << "interruptions " << "frequently." << std::endl;
}

void threadSafeTask(int * input, Log * log){
  *log << lock << "Executing" << " thread '" << *input << "', " << "not expecting " << "interruptions." << std::endl << unlock;
}

// Constructors (Most left out as irrelevant)
Log::Log(std::ostream & os): logFile(), logStream(logFile), guard(){
  logStream.rdbuf(os.rdbuf());
}

// Destructor
Log::~Log(){
  logFile.close();
}

// Output Operators
Log & Log::operator<<(const std::string & msg){
  logStream << msg;
  return *this;
}

Log & Log::operator<<(const int & msg){
  logStream << msg;
  return *this;
}

Log & Log::operator<<(std::ostream & (*man)(std::ostream &)){
  logStream << man;
  return *this;
}

Log & Log::operator<<(std::ios_base & (*man)(std::ios_base &)){
  logStream << man;
  return *this;
}

Log & Log::operator<<(Log & (*man)(Log &)){
  man(*this);
  return *this;
}

// Manipulator functions.
Log & lock(Log & log){
  log.guard.lock();
  return log;
}

Log & unlock(Log & log){
  log.guard.unlock();
  return log;
}
```

It works for me on Ubuntu 12.04 g++, compiled with:

```
g++ LogThreadTest.cpp -o log -std=c++0x -lpthread
```

The bits relevant to making custom manipulators was shamelessly cribbed from [here](http://www.two-sdg.demon.co.uk/curbralan/papers/WritingStreamManipulators.html) but don't blame them for my incompetent copypasta.

Comment: It is a mistake to not use RAII here.

Comment: IMHO, a lock-less FIFO will be a much better idea here .. somehow thread pausing for logging doesn't appeal.

Comment: Relying on users to lock and unlock something is unreliable. One option is to have your log file take messages from the users concurrently, and serialize them by putting them in a single queue and run them in a separate thread. So from the multiple users' point of view, the calls are non-blocking, but in fact there is no interleaving. See [this talk by Herb Sutter](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-Concurrency-and-Parallelism) for more info. I went through the exercise of implementing a working version of his concurrent object wrapper.

Comment: Quite right re: RAII; I should be closing the fstream on destruction, yeah? I stripped that out when I was cutting down the example, but removing the fstream broke the ostream, so I put it back but not the fstream.close() in the destructor...

I dunno if I want to do anything with the ostream on destruction - if the Log instance is constructed with cerr/cout, I don't want to mess with it, and if derived from the fstream (it is if Log is constructed with filename string or fstream, those constructors not shown here) it will be handled when that gets closed, correct?

Comment: "Relying on users to lock and unlock something is unreliable."

As I said, I'm willing to accept that - but again, any suggestions as to making this error at compile time would be appreciated.

Comment: "One option is to have your log file take messages from the users concurrently, and serialize them by putting them in a single queue and run them in a separate thread." and "a lock-less FIFO will be a much better idea here"

Yep, saw those approaches, but I found them needlessly complicated. Maybe it's just me, but we have a contended resource, so a mutex is the natural response, and having that handled by the owner of the resource seems right, rather than leaving it 'out in the open'. Plus, 'lock' and 'unlock' manipulators fit right in with the normal use of streams.

Comment: "somehow thread pausing for logging doesn't appeal."

I can see that, but if it's going into a FIFO there's still going to be a delay between 'write log message' and 'save message to disk', so there's still a risk of message loss in catastrophic system failure.

Comment: Code reviews really belong on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a code review, which belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com.


Comment: use of templates (maybe SFINAE is needed also) could allow you to set up RAII (scoped) locking semantics for any stream (template argument is the stream you want locking semantics for).  The template is used to make a different mutex for each separate stream, without which all different streams would share a single mutex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bad idea.
Imagine this:

```
void foo()
{
    throw std::exception();
}

log << lock << "Write" << foo() << " I" << " want" << std::endl << unlock;
                          ^
                          exception!
```

This leaves your `Log` locked. Which is bad as other threads might be waiting to lock.
This also happens everytime you simply *forget* to do the `unlock`.
You should use RAII here:

```
// just providing a scope
{
    std::lock_guard<Log> lock(log);
    log << "Write" << foo() << " I" << " want" << std::endl;
}
```

You'd need to adjust your `lock` and `unlock` methods to have the signatures `void lock()` and `void unlock()` and make them member functions of the class `Log`.

---

On the other hand, that's rather bulky. Note that in C++11, using `std::cout` is thread-safe. So you can easily do

```
std::stringstream stream;
stream << "Write" << foo() << " I" << " want" << std::endl;
std::cout << stream.str();
```

which is completely free of additional locks.

Comment: Tough decision on which answer to accept, but  even though the answer from Useless provided a great solution, this one answered the question more directly. Cheers to all.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to pass the lock manipulator explicitly, you can use a sentry (with RAII semantics, as Hans Passant says)

```
class Log{
public:
  Log(std::ostream & os);
  ~Log();

  class Sentry {
      Log &log_;
  public:
      Sentry(Log &l) log_(l) { log_.lock(); }
      ~Sentry() { log_.unlock(); }

      // Input Functions just forward to log_.logStream
      Sentry& operator<<(const std::string & msg);
      Sentry& operator<<(const int & msg);
      Sentry& operator<<(std::ostream & (*man)(std::ostream &)); // Handles manipulators like endl.
      Sentry& operator<<(std::ios_base & (*man)(std::ios_base &)); // Handles manipulators like hex.
    };

    template <typename T>
    Sentry operator<<(T t) { return Sentry(*this) << t; }
    void lock();
    void unlock();

private:
  std::fstream logFile;
  std::ostream & logStream;
  std::mutex guard;
};
```

Now, writing

```
Log::log << "Write" << " what" << " I" << " want" << foo() << std::endl;
```

will:

1. create a temporary Sentry object

   - which locks the Log object
2. ... forwards each `operator<<` call to the parent Log instance ...
3. and then goes out of scope at the end of the expression (or if `foo` throws)

   - which unlocks the Log object

---

Although this is safe, it also creates a lot of contention (that mutex is locked longer than I'd usually like, while formatting a message). A lower-contention approach would be to do the formatting into local storage (either thread-local or scope-local) with no locking at all, and then hold a lock just long enough to move that into a shared logging queue.

Comment: Ah, I had entirely misinterpreted Hans Passant's reference to RAII, but this clarifies it, and it's a beautiful solution, thanks! Why couldn't I find this on my search for an elegant approach? :D

Comment: I'm afraid I can't recall where I first saw this idea. BTW, you can clean it up by giving Sentry a std::unique_lock member instead of calling lock & unlock directly (you get the move ctor and dtor for free, then).

Comment: @Useless The usual solution is to have a thread local streambuf and ostream object, which _only_ flushes when explicitly requested to do so, and locks around the flush.  And use the RAII approach to trigger the flush.

Comment: Although something looks wrong to me.  Your `Log::operator<<` returns `Sentry` by value, which means it might be copied (in which case, you'll unlock too early).  Typically, you'll get away with it, because RVO will eliminate the copy, but I don't like the fact that code counts on RVO to be correct.  (I know I first used something like this 20 years ago, when RVO wasn't universal, and I needed extra code to simulate move semantics.)

Comment: Dang, I can't even upvote this, sorry - I accepted the answer from Stefan as it more directly pointed out why my approach was flawed, but this bit of edification was hugely appreciated, even if this interface won't let me express it.

Comment: @JamesKanze - Yes, moving the Sentry is probably safest - I have a horrible feeling I might have written an auto_ptr-style destructive copy before that was available. I guess it's either that or ref-counting. Definitely agree that un-synchronized local formatting and synchronized flush is a better choice in general.

Comment: @umlimo - don't worry about it. Besides, as James points out, this is a known and documented technique, so I can't take credit for inventing it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really a very good idea, since someone will fatally
forget the `unlock` at some point, causing all of the threads to
hang at the next log.  There's also the issue of what happens if
one of the expressions you're logging throws.  (It shouldn't
happen, since you don't want to have actual behavior in the log
statement, and things that don't have any behavior shouldn't
throw.  But you never know.)

The usual solution for logging is to use a special temporary
object, which grabs the lock in its constructor, and frees it in
the destructor (and also does a flush, and ensures that there is
a trailing `'\n'`).  This can be done very elegantly in C++11,
using move semantics (because you generally want to create the
instance of the temporary in a function, but the temporary whose
destructor should act is outside the function); in C++03, you
need to allow copying, and ensure that it is only the final copy
which releases the lock.

Roughly speaking, your `Log` class would look something like:

```
struct LogData
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> myLock
    std::ostream myStream;

    LogData( std::unique_lock<std::mutex>&& lock,
             std::streambuf* logStream )
        :  myLock( std::move( lock ) )
        ,  myStream( logStream )
    {
    }

    ~LogData()
    {
        myStream.flush();
    }
};

class Log
{
    LogData* myDest;
public:
    Log( LogData* dest )
        : myDest( dest )
    {
    }
    Log( Log&& other )
        : myDest( other.myDest )
    {
        other.myDest = nullptr;
    }
    ~Log()
    {
        if ( myDest ) {
            delete myDest;
        }
    }
    Log& operator=( Log const& other ) = delete;

    template <typename T>
    Log& operator<<( T const& obj )
    {
        if ( myDest != nullptr ) {
            myDest->myStream << obj;
        }
    }
};
```

(If your compiler doesn't have move semantics, you'll have to
fake it somehow.  If worst comes to worst, you can just make the
single pointer member of Log mutable, and put the same code in
a copy constructor with the traditional signature.  Ugly, but as
a work-around...)

In this solution, you would have a function `log`, which returns
an instance of this class, with either a valid `LogData`
(allocated dynamically), or a null pointer, depending on whether
logging is active or not.  (It's possible to avoid the dynamic
allocation, by using a static instance of a `LogData` which has
functions to start a log record, and to end it, but it is
a little bit more complicated.)

Comment: This is sort of cool, but is there really a benefit in contrast to `stringstream`ing the message and then invoking `operator<<` on the underlying `ostream`? Also, does the move ctor of `unique_lock` lock the mutex? Otherwise, I think you don't actually ever acquire the lock, right? Or do you pass in an already locked `unique_lock`? Little confused here.

Comment: @thokra There are two important benefits compared to using `ostringstream`: the first is that no formatting will take place if logging is not active, and the second is that I actually use a special `streambuf`, which has special functions to inject code at the start of each line, and to ensure that the flushed sequence ends with a `'\n'`.  I also use a macro to call `log`, so I can automatically pass it `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`.  And I'm constantly using the same streambuf object, so its buffer soon reaches the maximum size, and there are no more allocations.

Comment: The lock is acquired in the function `log`, which returns the `Log`, and must be moved into the `LogData` when it is constructed.  (In my original code, the `log` function had a few things to do before constructing the `LogData` anyway.  And I didn't have thread local storage at the time, so the option of having a the streambuf in thread local storage, and only locking during the flush, wasn't available to me.