# how to run multiple operator<< in one go

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I have implemented a custom logger where I dump information to the corresponding file:

**like this:**

```
Logger::log["log_file"] << "Hi" << "Hi again" << "\n";
```

The implementation of the `operator <<` is as below. Kindly note the place where the buffer is dumped into the stream when it reaches a limit:

```
//This is the function signature of std::endl and some other manipulators
typedef CoutType& (*StandardEndLine)(CoutType&);
/// This method defines an operator<< to take in std::endl
BasicLogger& operator<<(StandardEndLine manip);
/// write the log items to buffer
template <typename T>
BasicLogger & operator<< (const T& val)
{
    std::stringstream *out = BasicLogger::getOut();
    *out << val;
    if(out->tellp() > 512000/*500KB*/){
        flushLog();
    }
    return *this;
}
```

My problem is in the lines that have multiple `<<`s :

```
Logger::log["log_file"] << "Hi" << "Hi again" << "\n";
```

after executing `<< "Hi"`, the buffer can get full and flushing to the stream is performed.
This is not desirable for me . *I am looking for a solution to ignore that limit(500KB) if a line has not ended yet.*

**Example scenario:**
This problem is highlighted when the application writes buffers filled by different threads to the same file: the last line of the first buffer is half written, when the second buffer from another thread writes another 500kb to the file before I can complete the last line of the first buffer.

I appreciate your thoughts and solutions.
thanks

Comment: When you're writing to the same stream and file from multiple threads, you need locking/synchronization.

Comment: Nearly a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10110048/179910

Comment: So, if adding "Hi" to the buffer causes it to be full so that it needs to be flushed, but you want to prevent that until the line ends, where do you propose storing the additional "Hi again" and "\n" bytes until you decide it's acceptable for the buffer to be flushed? The buffer is full, so it can't hold more data... I suppose you could rework the buffer handler to resize the buffer in such a case, but that's needlessly complicated...

Comment: @AndrewMedico the whole idea behind having multiple buffers was to avoid locking as much as possible. in fact `BasicLogger::getOut()` is an accessor to a map whose key is the thread_id :)

Comment: @twalberg by full, I meant *my* limit of buffer which is 500KB is over. It means, the buffer had been filling up by hundreds of other lines and when writing the last line , the limit (500KB) was reached. I dont mind to ignore this limit just to complete this last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Useless's suggestion (A suggestion shot by a user called [Useless](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212858/useless)!!!),
I solved my issue using `Sentry`(temporary) objects:

1. `Logger::log["log_file"]` will return the correct instance of `BasicLogger`
2. `operator<<` in `BasicLogger` will return a copy of a `Sentry` object.
3. The subsequent `<<`s will be taken care of by  `operator<<` in the `Sentry` object
4. Sentry will eventually goes out of scope upon hitting **`;`** where its `destructor` will do the main job:

> ```
> class BasicLogger {
> /// operator overload. write the log items to buffer
>   template<typename T>
>   Sentry operator<<(const T& val) {
>      Sentry t(*this,*getOut());
>      t << val;//do the first << here
>      return t;            
>   }
> //...
>   class Sentry {
>       std::stringstream &out;
>       BasicLogger &basicLogger;
>   public:
>       Sentry(BasicLogger & basicLogger_, std::stringstream &out_) :
>               out(out_), basicLogger(basicLogger_) {
>       }
>       Sentry(const Sentry& t) :
>               basicLogger(t.basicLogger), out(t.out) {
>       }
>       template<typename T>
> /// operator overload
>       Sentry & operator<<(const T& val) {
>           out << val;
>           return *this;
>       }
>       ~Sentry() {
> // by some googling this estimated hardcode value promises less cycles to write to a file
>           if (out.tellp() > 512000/*500KB*/) {
>               basicLogger.flushLog();
>           }
>       }
>   };
> //...
> };
>
> class Logger {
> //...
> public:
>   static Logger log;
>   virtual BasicLogger & operator[](const std::string &key);
>   virtual ~Logger();
> };
> ```

Answer (score 4):

The traditional solution to grouping multiple `<<` into a single flush is to use a temporary sentry object which is destroyed at the end of the statement.

The destructor would flush (if required), and you can even have it append a newline automatically if that's what you want.  As per Andrew Medico's comment, the sentry ctor/dtor should lock/unlock as well, if you need synchronization.

An alternative is to gather everything into a local ostringstream in the sentry, and then you only have to lock/write/flush/unlock a single string from the dtor.

Details:

1. your `Logger::log["log_file"]` operator should return a temporary object with the behaviour you chose from the options above
2. your various `<<` are operator calls taking as the first argument, and returning, a reference to your sentry type
3. at the `;`, the temporary sentry goes out of scope and does any flushing work in its destructor.

Note that if you're just delegating to an existing ostream, you can easily have a single templated `Logger::sentry& operator<< (Logger::sentry&, T)`.

---

Edit: I *thought* I'd done this before: the question isn't a duplicate, but the answer is. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19520409/212858

Comment: This seems to be a very nice solution. For now I still dont think I will need locking. I am trying to imagine how the example usage of `Logger::sentry& operator<< (Logger::sentry&, T)` will look like? and then, how to implement it. I can,somewhat, see how the destructor of sentry looks like but can't imagine how it is temporarily created in the first place and doesn't go out of scope among multiple `>>`s.I guess I need your help. can you please provide an example? no need to worry aout synchronization for now coz `out = getOut();` will return a stream specific to the current thread. thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for a solution to ignore that limit(500KB) **if a line has not ended yet**.

Why not just check that the last character is a '\n' before flushing the log?

If I knew what was in T, I would give you an example. If its a c++11 string you can just do:

```
char ch = val.getString().back();
if(out->tellp() > 512000/*500KB*/  && ch == '\n'){
   flushLog();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply flag a carrage return:

```
bool ended = out.str().find('\n') != string::npos;
if(out->tellp() > 512000/*500KB*/ && ended) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the implementation of the `flushLog` method. I assume your implementation writes the contents of the internal `stringstream` into a file and clears it. You can output the contents of the `stringstream` only up to the last newline:

```
void Whatever::flushLog()
{
    std::stringstream& out = *BasicLogger::getOut();
    std::string stuff = out.str();
    size_t pos_of_newline = stuff.rfind('\n');
    if (pos_of_newline != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::string write_it_to_file = stuff.substr(0, pos_of_newline + 1);
        ... write it to file
        std::string leftover = stuff.substr(pos_of_newline + 1);
        out.str(leftover);
    }
}
```

The code is only an idea; I didn't check it - maybe there are some bugs. In additon: the `str()` call duplicates the contents of the `stringstream`; you might want to use its `rdbuf` instead (I have no experience with `rdbuf`, so cannot recommend anything).

Comment: or..., we can do this check even before going into `flushLog`. This way we wont mess with the crazy implementations of `flushLog`(crazy: the buffer had been previously created on heap, when got full, its address is pushed into a lockfree queue(in 'flushLog`) to be written to the corresponding file later by an IO thread and then delete the buffer(s). A `new` empty buffer is replaced with the full buffer when the full buffe is pushed to the queue.